# JSfiddle code is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

I am trying to transfering elements from one listbox to another listbox in html. For this I am using below code:

Question ::--This code I found from a link by stackoverflow which redirects to jsfiddle site, it is working on that site but not working here??

```
<html>
<header>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){

        $("#list1 > option:selected").each(function(){
            $(this).remove().appendTo("#list2");

        });
    });

    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#list2 > option:selected").each(function(){
            $(this).remove().appendTo("#list1");
        });
    });
 });
 </script>
 </header>
<body>

<div>
    <h3>List A</h3>
    <select id="list1" multiple="multiple" rows=2>
        <option value=1>Option 1</option>
        <option value=2>Option 2</option>
        <option value=3>Option 3</option>
        <option value=4>Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input id="button1" type="button" value="Move to List B" />
</div>
<div>
    <h3>List B</h3>
    <select id="list2" multiple="multiple" rows=2>        
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input id="button2" type="button" value="Move to List A" />
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

I know this is very silly question but I am a beginner.

What I did wrong here?? please help me ..

Comment: Did you include jQuery? FYI the [`<header>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) tag is not the same as the [**`<head>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head) tag

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/FpC79/ like anOG said, you probably forgot to include jQuery

Comment: add jquery js file in header.

Comment: Oh my God !! u all r right,I didn't include jquery files. I am such a stupid instead of <head> i was taking <header>.Thnkx all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add jquery file in `<head></head>` section like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

then it works fine.